# R language: Converting images with regular dots to data frame

Tags: r, image, identification

I have many ultraviolet images (*.png) each with 96 "wells" that appear as circles.  These wells are arranged in a 8 by 12 fashion.  Please see example below.

In each image, some of the 96 circles are lighted up (reacting to UV), and some of them are not.  I would like to give a number to each circle, then identify them as either "lighted up" or "not lighted up"  (with a pre-defined cutoff).

What do you think is the easiest way to achieve this in R?
I've been playing with the package `imager` without much success.

One more note:  Not all of my images have the same magnification (ie, circles are not always the same sizes across files, but within a file, they are roughly the same in size).

[image: Here is an example of one of the images (embedded)]

Comment: Can you give examples of a couple of other sizes please? Are the wells always in 8x12 arrangement? Can the images sometimes be rotated?

Comment: Thank you, Mark.  Yes, (i) the wells are always in the 8x12 arrangement, (ii) the images are always in the same orientation, (iii) by "other sizes" I meant sometimes the zoom when the picture was taken would be further away while the proportion of circles stay the same.  Does this make sense?

Comment: I think my initial approach would be to trim the extraneous black around the edges and then resize what's left up to a standardised size. Then I'd have a mask of the same size that had all 96 wells identified on it. Then apply the mask to the standardised image and count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")
library(EBImage)

fn = YOURFILE
img <- readImage(fn)

# remove outer frame
border <- 5 # 5px
dims <- dim(img)
img <- img[border:(dims[1]-border), border:(dims[2]-border),1:dims[3]]

# some despectling
img <- medianFilter(img,size=10) # blur image 
# display(img) # check if blurring is fine

# get plate mask.
highpass_rect <- .02 # if images are darker, lower this
rect <- bwlabel(dilate(img>highpass_rect, makeBrush(size=3)))
rect <- rect > 0 # remove background
# display(rect) # check if plate is recognized correctly

highpass_light <- .4 # again, darker images need lower values here for the light objects
# get single light objects
img <- bwlabel(img > highpass_light)
# display(img) # # check if all lights are displayed

# get dimensions of rectangle
rect_mid <- round(dim(rect@.Data[,,1]) / 2)
x_range <- c(min(which(rect@.Data[,rect_mid[2],1])), max(which(rect@.Data[,rect_mid[2],1])))
y_range <- c(min(which(rect@.Data[rect_mid[1],,1])), max(which(rect@.Data[rect_mid[1],,1])))

# now substract border of plate
# measured from the image you provided. 'should' scale to other images as well
# x: left 69px, right: 74px, ROI: 1085
x_range[1] <- x_range[1] + round((diff(x_range)) * (74/(1085+74+69)))
x_range[2] <- x_range[2] - round((diff(x_range)) * (69/(1085+74+69)))

# y: top 17px, bottom: 12px, ROI: 722
y_range[1] <- y_range[1] + round((diff(y_range)) * (17/(722+17+12)))
y_range[2] <- y_range[2] - round((diff(y_range)) * (12/(722+17+12)))

# get pixel ranges for the 12x8 cells
# we will use this as indexes in df
x_cuts <- c(rep(NA,x_range[1]), cut(x_range[1]:x_range[2],12,dig.lab = 0,include.lowest = T,labels=F))
y_cuts <- c(rep(NA,y_range[1]), cut(y_range[1]:y_range[2],8,dig.lab = 0,include.lowest = T,labels=F))

# create 12X8 matrix
df <- matrix(rep(0,12*8),nrow=8,dimnames = list(levels(cut(y_range,8,dig.lab = 0)),
                                                levels(cut(x_range,12,dig.lab = 0,include.lowest = T))))
# now go through lighted objects
for (i in 1:(dim(table(img))-1)) { 
  # img == i is light nr i
  # get position of object
  pos <- which(img@.Data[,,1] == i, arr.ind = T)

  # add up enlighted pixels in df
  for (row in 1:nrow(pos)) {
    df[y_cuts[pos[row,2]], x_cuts[pos[row,1]]] <- df[y_cuts[pos[row,2]], x_cuts[pos[row,1]]] + 1
  }
}

print(df)

>                  [143,235] (235,326] (326,417] (417,508] (508,599] (599,690] (690,781] (781,872] (872,963] (963,1.05e+03] (1.05e+03,1.14e+03] (1.14e+03,1.24e+03]
> (90,1.8e+02]           1116         0         0         0      1974         0         0         0         0              0                   0                   0
> (1.8e+02,2.7e+02]         0      2528         0         0         0      2528         0         0         0              0                1938                 845
> (2.7e+02,3.6e+02]         0      2479      2518      2430         0         0         0         0         0           2477                2409                   0
> (3.6e+02,4.5e+02]      1731      2339         0      2601         0      2775         0         0         0              0                   0                   0
> (4.5e+02,5.4e+02]         0         0         0      2549         0      1033         0         0         0              0                   0                   0
> (5.4e+02,6.3e+02]      2370      2449      2570         0         0         0         0      2555         0              0                   0                   0
> (6.3e+02,7.3e+02]         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0              0                1836                2348
> (7.3e+02,8.2e+02]         0      1447      1760         0         0         0         0         0         0              0                2303                   0
```

Comment: THANK YOU psychOle!  Your code is magical !!!!  How can I thank you, and what's the best way  to credit you when I use this?  Follow up question:  I'm new to EBImage so please excuse a perhaps a simple problem.  I run your script through a second image, and the detection is off.  I'm still trying to understand your script.  Which part do I change to adjust this?  Any pointer would be helpful.  I CAN'T THANK YOU ENOUGH ALREADY!!!  Second image:  http://tinypic.com/r/312y5iq/9

Comment: Hey Subaru, you can run `display(img)` after each step to see if the results look reasonable. I added some comments so that you might get the idea. 
I've also edited the code to remove the outer 5px of the image, as your 2nd image has a white line on the right side, which confuses `bwlabel()`.

Comment: About giving credit: I think stack overflow content is under cc-by-sa. If you are about to publish a paper, you could think of naming me in the acknowledgement :)

Comment: Hi Subaru. The answer I added on 5 May works with the alternative image in your link. It expects the image of the plate to be parallel to the image border. If it isn't you can adjust the code to accommodate or--better--rotate the image to be parallel.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but the question addresses a problem I often face. Perhaps a more general solution may be of interest to others. Here is a suggested solution that uses a few more features of the `EBImage` package and with interacts with the user. It can be applied to multiwell dishes of any geometry.

```
# EBImage needs to be available
  if (!require(EBImage)) {
    source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    biocLite("EBImage")
    library(EBImage)
  }

# Read the image and examine it
  fn <- file.choose() # select saved image
  img <- readImage(fn)
  img <- channel(img, "gray") # gray scale for simplicity
  plot(img)

# Define the geometry of the plate
  nx <- 12 # number of columns
  ny <- 8 # number of rows
  nwells <- seq_len(nx*ny) # index of each well in plate

# Use locator() to interactively define the upper left "corner"
# of the top left and bottom right well with a red mark to confirm
  p <- locator(2, type = "p", col = 2)
```

[image: Plate image with two selected points]

```
# Calculate distance between wells and create coordinates in xx, yy
  dx <- abs(diff(p$x))/(nx - 1)
  dy <- abs(diff(p$y))/(ny - 1)
  ix <- (nwells - 1) %% nx  # index for rows
  iy <- (nwells - 1) %/% nx # index for columns
  xx <- ix*dx + p$x[1] # the first point must be the upper left well
  yy <- iy*dy + p$y[1]

# Confirm the calculated coordinates with red dots
  points(xx, yy, pch = 16, col = 2)
```

[image: Plate image with confirming dots]

Now an object mask will be created to use with the `computeFeatures` family of functions. The mask is created in steps with the following code.

```
# First a pure black image
  mask <- Image(0, dim = dim(img)) # black image same size as image

# Add white rectangles allowing 5% space between rectangles
  for (x in xx)
    for (y in yy) 
      mask[x:(x + 0.95*dx), y:(y + 0.95*dy)] <- 1

# Convert image to an 'object mask' 
  mask <- bwlabel(mask)

# One could draw circular masks with drawCircle() but this is very,
# very inefficient and doesn't improve the quality of the data
#
# mask <- Image(0, dim = dim(img)) # black image same size as image
# for (x in xx)
#   for (y in yy) 
#     mask <- drawCircle(mask, x + 0.5*dx, y + 0.5*dy,
#       radius = 0.95*dx/2, col = 1, fill = TRUE)

# Show mask on top of original image
  plot(paintObjects(mask, img, col = "white"))
```

[image: Plate image with object masks]

```
# Use the computeFeatures family of functions to measure the mean intensity
  M <- computeFeatures.basic(mask, img) # a matrix of values is returned
  options(digits = 4)
  head(M)
>   b.mean   b.sd   b.mad  b.q001  b.q005  b.q05 b.q095 b.q099
> 1 0.2800 0.2114 0.18605 0.04706 0.05882 0.2118 0.7451 0.8959
> 2 0.1778 0.0981 0.09303 0.05490 0.06275 0.1569 0.3882 0.4745
> 3 0.1817 0.1028 0.10465 0.05098 0.05882 0.1569 0.4039 0.4824
> 4 0.1854 0.1029 0.10465 0.05490 0.06275 0.1608 0.3961 0.4880
> 5 0.3300 0.2425 0.23256 0.05490 0.06667 0.2510 0.7882 0.9451
> 6 0.1967 0.1076 0.11047 0.05490 0.06275 0.1765 0.4157 0.5216

# Extract the mean intensity and examine with a simple barplot
  val <- M[,"b.mean"]
  barplot(val)

# Combination of median and mad provides a fair estimate of the cutoff
  bgnd <- median(val) + mad(val)
  abline(h = bgnd, col = 2)
```

[image: Barplot of values with estimate of background]

```
# Collect values in labeled data.frame and score the values
  df <- data.frame(row = factor(LETTERS[iy+1]), column = factor(ix+1),
    val = val, positive = val > bgnd)
  head(df)
>   row column    val positive
> 1   A      1 0.2800     TRUE
> 2   A      2 0.1778    FALSE
> 3   A      3 0.1817    FALSE
> 4   A      4 0.1854    FALSE
> 5   A      5 0.3300     TRUE
> 6   A      6 0.1967    FALSE

# And for visual confirmation...or to check the background value
  plot(img)
  text(xx[df$positive], yy[df$positive], "+", col = 2, cex = 2)
```

[image: Plate image with visual confirmation of positive samples]